# Need to read data from png file and save it to the new one, how? C++

Tags: c++, file, binary, filestream

I try to read data from one PNG file, and want to write this data to the new file and save it.
I do such stuff like that:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\dev\\1.png", "rb");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);
char *buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
size_t result = fread(buffer, 1, size, fp);
FILE *tmpf = fopen("C:\\dev\\1_1.png", "wb");
fputs(buffer, tmpf);
fflush(tmpf);
fclose(tmpf);
```

I've got problem, that second file only has in its content, only that: ‰PNG SUB

In debugging , I have checked, long size = 652521, and size_t result has got the same size...
Don't understand, why I can't write all data to the second file...

Comment: `sizeof(char) * size` will always equal `size`

Comment: nah... I have found solution, I ought to use: fwrite(buffer, 1, result, tmpf);

Comment: Does `fread()` and other file operations succeed?

Comment: yes, they do! I have found solution successfully ( look upper )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `fputs` - use `fwrite` - `fputs` is for strings and will terminate on the first zero byte.

Change:

```
fputs(buffer, tmpf);
```

to:

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, size, tmpf);
```